# One-Hot-Encode categorical variables and scale continuous ones simultaneouely

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm confused because it's going to be a problem if you first do `OneHotEncoder` and then `StandardScaler` because the scaler will also scale the columns previously transformed by `OneHotEncoder`. Is there a way to perform encoding and scaling at the same time and then concatenate the results together?

Comment: OneHotEncoder has a parameter `categorical_features` to specify the columns to encode. And you can use the [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) to do both the things separately and then merge them together.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sure thing. Just separately scale and one-hot-encode the separate columns as needed:

```
# Import libraries and download example data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
print(dataset.head(5))

# Define which columns should be encoded vs scaled
columns_to_encode = ['rank']
columns_to_scale  = ['gre', 'gpa']

# Instantiate encoder/scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
ohe    = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

# Scale and Encode Separate Columns
scaled_columns  = scaler.fit_transform(dataset[columns_to_scale]) 
encoded_columns =    ohe.fit_transform(dataset[columns_to_encode])

# Concatenate (Column-Bind) Processed Columns Back Together
processed_data = np.concatenate([scaled_columns, encoded_columns], axis=1)
```

Comment: This principles outlined in this answer, also work for Pyspark

Answer (score 10):

Scikit-learn from version 0.20 provides `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer` to do **Column Transformer with Mixed Types**. You can scale the numeric features and one-hot encode the categorical ones together. Below is the offical example(you can find the code [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) ):

```
# Author: Pedro Morales <part.morales@gmail.com>
#
# License: BSD 3 clause

from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

np.random.seed(0)

# Read data from Titanic dataset.
titanic_url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amueller/'
               'scipy-2017-sklearn/091d371/notebooks/datasets/titanic3.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(titanic_url)

# We will train our classifier with the following features:
# Numeric Features:
# - age: float.
# - fare: float.
# Categorical Features:
# - embarked: categories encoded as strings {'C', 'S', 'Q'}.
# - sex: categories encoded as strings {'female', 'male'}.
# - pclass: ordinal integers {1, 2, 3}.

# We create the preprocessing pipelines for both numeric and categorical data.
numeric_features = ['age', 'fare']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_features = ['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

# Append classifier to preprocessing pipeline.
# Now we have a full prediction pipeline.
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'))])

X = data.drop('survived', axis=1)
y = data['survived']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("model score: %.3f" % clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

**Caution**: this method is EXPERIMENTAL, some behaviors may change between releases without deprecation.

Answer (score 7):

There are presently numerous methods to achieve the outcome required by the OP. 3 ways to do this are

1. `np.concatenate()` - see [this answer to the OP's question, already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798994/4057186)
2. [`scikit-learn`'s `ColumnTransformer`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer)

   - originally suggested in [this SO answer to the OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751743/4057186)
3. [`scikit-learn`'s `FeatureUnion`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#feature-union-with-heterogeneous-data-sources)

   - also shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703546/4057186)

Using the example posted by @Max Power [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798994/4057186), below is a minimum working snippet that does what the OP is looking for and brings together the transformed columns into a single Pandas dataframe. The output of all 3 approaches is shown

The common code for all 3 methods is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Import libraries and download example data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

# Define which columns should be encoded vs scaled
columns_to_encode = ['rank']
columns_to_scale  = ['gre', 'gpa']

# Instantiate encoder/scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
ohe    = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
```

**Method 1.** see code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798994/4057186). To show the output, can use

```
print(pd.DataFrame(processed_data).head())
```

Output of Method 1.

```
          0         1    2    3    4    5
0 -1.800263  0.579072  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.626668  0.736929  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.840134  1.605143  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.453316 -0.525927  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
4 -0.586797 -1.209974  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

**Method 2.**

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


p = Pipeline(
    [("coltransformer", ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("assessments", Pipeline([("scale", scaler)]), columns_to_scale),
            ("ranks", Pipeline([("encode", ohe)]), columns_to_encode),
        ]),
    )]
)

print(pd.DataFrame(p.fit_transform(dataset)).head())
```

Output of Method 2.

```
          0         1    2    3    4    5
0 -1.800263  0.579072  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.626668  0.736929  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.840134  1.605143  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.453316 -0.525927  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
4 -0.586797 -1.209974  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

**Method 3.**

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion


class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, df):
        return df[self.key]

p = Pipeline([("union", FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[
        ("assessments", Pipeline([
            ("selector", ItemSelector(key=columns_to_scale)),
            ("scale", scaler)
            ]),
        ),
        ("ranks", Pipeline([
            ("selector", ItemSelector(key=columns_to_encode)),
            ("encode", ohe)
            ]),
        ),
    ]))
])

print(pd.DataFrame(p.fit_transform(dataset)).head())
```

Output of Method 3.

```
          0         1    2    3    4    5
0 -1.800263  0.579072  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.626668  0.736929  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.840134  1.605143  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.453316 -0.525927  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
4 -0.586797 -1.209974  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

**Explanation**

1. Method 1. is already explained.
2. Methods 2. and  3. accept the full dataset but only perform specific actions on subsets of the data. The modified/processed subsets are brought together (combined) into the final output.

**Details**

```
pandas==0.23.4
numpy==1.15.2
scikit-learn==0.20.0
```

**Additional Notes**

The 3 methods shown here are probably not the only possibilities....I am sure there are other methods to do this.

**SOURCE USED**

[Updated link to `binary.csv` dataset](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't get your point as `OneHotEncoder` is used for nominal data, and `StandardScaler` is used for numeric data. So you shouldn't use them together for your data.

Comment: PLease tell me how to employ `OneHotEncoder` on nominal data (especially of **string** type). I need this feature badly as anyone else.

Comment: You can use first a LabelEncoder then a OneHotEncoder:

`import numpy as np
winds=np.array([['SE'],['NW'],['NW'],['NE'],['SE']])

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
int_encoded = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(winds[:,0]).reshape((len(winds),-1))
one_hot_encoded = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(int_encoded)

# you get this:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])`