# How to use StandardScaler inside a pipeline only on certain values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, normalization

I have a problem. I want to use `StandardScaler()`, but my dataset contains certain `OneHotEncoding` values and other values that should be **not** be scaled. But if I'm running the `StandardScaler()` all the values are scaled. So is there an option to run this method only on certain values inside a pipeline?

I found this question: [One-Hot-Encode categorical variables and scale continuous ones simultaneouely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798377/one-hot-encode-categorical-variables-and-scale-continuous-ones-simultaneouely) with the below code

```py
columns = ['rank']
columns_to_scale  = ['gre', 'gpa']

scaler = StandardScaler()
ohe    = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

# Concatenate (Column-Bind) Processed Columns Back Together
processed_data = np.concatenate([scaled_columns, encoded_columns], axis=1)
```

So is there an option to only run the `StandardScaler()` inside a `pipeline` on only certain values and the other values should be merged to the scaled values?
So the pipeline should only use StandardScaler on the values `'xy', 'xyz'`.

**StandardScaler Class**

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class StandardScaler_with_certain_features(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns_to_scale):
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        

    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        scaler.fit(X_train) # only std.fit on train set
        X_train_nor = scaler.transform(X_train.values)

    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        return X
```

**Pipeline**

```py
columns_to_scale  = ['xy', 'xyz']
    
steps = [('standard_scaler', StandardScaler_with_certain_features(columns_to_scale)),
         ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(estimator=LogisticRegression(max_iter=100))),
         ('lasso', Lasso(alpha=0.03))]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=30)

parameteres = { }

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5)                
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
                    
print("score = %3.2f" %(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print('Training set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_train,y_train)))
print('Test set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))

# Prediction
y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)
print("RMSE Val:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred, squared=False))
```

Comment: Not sure I get your point as the post you are mentioning seems already specifying common techniques to achieve what you want, but perhaps I'm misinterpreting the question...

Comment: Another option I see (besides the one given by the answer) might be to create a class that instead of applying the scaling as you're doing, somehow selects the columns you want to apply the scaling on; then you might call its constructor within a pipeline that selects column first and then applies the scaling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can include a [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) in the `Pipeline` in order to apply the `StandardScaler` only to certain columns. You need to set `remainder='passthrough'` to make sure that the columns that are not scaled are concatenated with the ones that are scaled.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'z': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'xy': np.random.normal(2, 3, 100),
    'xyz': np.random.normal(4, 5, 100),
})

X = df.drop(labels=['y'], axis=1)
y = df['y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=30)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('scaler', StandardScaler(), ['xy', 'xyz'])],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('lasso', Lasso(alpha=0.03))
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I run your code I get `ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe KeyError: 'xy'`

Comment: This means that there is no column with name `'xy'` in the data frame with the features values. You would need to double check the column names of `X_train` and `X_test` and make sure to pass to the column transformer the correct names of the columns that need to be scaled.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I really appreciate it. Is there an option  to get the same result with X_train and X_test?

Comment: What I means is when I run your code with `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=30)` I run in the above error. So is there an option to use your code with a test/train split ?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer, but when you define the column transformer you need to make sure to replace `['xy', 'xyz']` with a list containing the actual names of the columns that need to be scaled.